# How to convert my simple ASP.NET MVC 4 application to AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to I convert my simple MVC4 todo list application to AJAX?

The ideal answer would give me the steps that would lead to a successful conversion of this example to AJAX.

Note: I don't need an AJAX tutorial so much as an understanding of how the ASP.NET MVC architecture supports it.

Side Question: Why does `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TodoItemToCreate)` bring back the value that was typed in even though the view model sets with `this.TodoItemToCreate = null`?

**Model**

```
public class TodosViewModel
{
    List<string> todoItems;
    public List<string> TodoItems
    { 
        get { return this.todoItems ?? (todoItems = new List<string>()); } 
    }

    [Display(Name="What do you need to do?")]
    public string TodoItemToCreate { get; set; }

    public bool AcceptTodoItem()
    {
        bool isThereAnItemToAccept = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.TodoItemToCreate);

        if (isThereAnItemToAccept)
        {
            this.TodoItems.Add(this.TodoItemToCreate);
            this.TodoItemToCreate = null;
        }

        return isThereAnItemToAccept;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class TodosController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new TodosViewModel());
    }

    public ActionResult Create(TodosViewModel todosViewModel)
    {
        todosViewModel.AcceptTodoItem();
        return View("Index", todosViewModel);
    }
}
```

**Index View**

```
@model Programming.LearnWeb.Models.TodosViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Todos";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Todos"))
{
    @Html.Partial("List")    
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TodoItemToCreate)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TodoItemToCreate)
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**List View**

```
@model Programming.LearnWeb.Models.TodosViewModel
    @{ int i = 0; }
<table>
    @foreach (var todoItem in Model.TodoItems)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Hidden("TodoItems[" + i++ + "]", todoItem)
                @todoItem
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this done on my own - the result is at https://github.com/gabrielgreen/Todos.Mvc if anyone is interested or has any comments.

I put a fair amount of effort in and would appreciate any feedback that indicates if I did it right.